# How to disable a div after click once in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in that case if you first time click show its show hello world its right but  again if you click on show its should not work. now its became a toggle but how can I do after one click its not working means after showing the hello world its should not again hide if you want to click again.
I'm also use pointer Event its also not working

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [show,setShow]=useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      {show?<h1>hello world</h1>:null}
      <div onClick={()=>{setShow(!show);return false;}}><span>show</span></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You need to disable the div after the first click. Is that the ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply modify your `onClick` with one time value set

```
onClick={()=>{setShow(true)}} //one time set
```

Full code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [show,setShow]=useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      {show?<h1>hello world</h1>:null}
      <div onClick={()=>{setShow(true)}}><span>show</span></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

If you want to disable that button after `show` update, you can set `disabled={show}` to that button

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [show,setShow]=useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      {show?<h1>hello world</h1>:null}
      <div onClick={()=>{setShow(true)}} disabled={show}><span>show</span></div>
    </>
  )
}
```